# Why do I get NameError in heroku (rails) console after enabling enhanced language Metrics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-cli

I enabled enhanced language metrics for the ruby language metrics in Heroku for a Ruby on Rails application, [following the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-ruby#getting-started) (barnes gem etc.). This worked successfully.

Later on I saw errors when inspecting something in the system through the rails console `heroku console --app my-rails-app-name`. Any call of a model constant example lead to the following output:

```
Running console on ⬢ my-rails-app-name... up, run.8724 (Standard-1X)
irb(main):001:0> MyModel.all.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/console:29:in `<main>'
        3: from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/console:29:in `load'
        2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/countries-3.0.0/bin/console:14:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant MyModel)
```

The work around is to run the rails console explicitly

```
heroku run rails console --app my-rails-app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the enhanced language metrics needs loading another build pack we can suspect that this is the reason for this. But don't give up! The order in which the build packs are executed can be configured. So drag the `heroku/metrics` buildpack above the `heroku/ruby` build pack, deploy one more time and afterwards you should be able to stick to your workflow :)

[image: Buildpacks settings screenshot]